# Detect Office version + friendly name

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to get the running version of Outlook in a friendly format AND if the version is 64-bit or 32-bit. So far:

```
Writeline(Current version: + new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application().Version;);
// Current version: 15.0.0.5031
```

Any hint?

Comment: Try other properties like Name / ProductCode, etc. as listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.application_members.aspx

Comment: Good attempt but no luck Name=Outlook / productCode ={GUID}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine whether Outlook is 32 or 64-bit using the registry:

```
static bool IsOutlook64Bit() {
    using (RegistryKey officeKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Office")) {
        if (officeKey != null) {
            Regex versionExp = new Regex(@"^[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+$");
            string maxVersion = officeKey.GetSubKeyNames()
                .Where(x => versionExp.IsMatch(x))
                .OrderByDescending(x => Decimal.Parse(x))
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(maxVersion)) {
                using (RegistryKey key = officeKey.OpenSubKey(maxVersion + @"\Outlook")) {
                    if (key != null) {
                        string bitness = Convert.ToString(key.GetValue("Bitness", null));
                        return bitness.Equals("x64", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Outlook not found on this machine.");
}
```

Note: The above method uses the latest version, which may not be the running version - however, in most cases this would be correct. Microsoft does not recommend installing multiple versions of any Office product. To be 100% accurate, you could parse the version number string you included in your question and match the major and minor components (e.g. `16.0`) instead of just taking the maximum.

The friendly name (e.g. Outlook 2016) isn't available via the object model and I don't believe it can be easily queried in the registry either. It may be easier to match the major component of the version number against a list of known values; e.g.

```
int major = (int)Decimal.Parse(maxVersion);
switch (major) {
    case 12:
        return "Outlook 2007";
    case 14:
        return "Outlook 2010";
    case 15:
        return "Outlook 2013";
    case 16:
        return "Outlook 2016":
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's nothing too good about getting a friendly name for this, you need to check the version number. Like Bradley's solution to get maxVersion of Outlook. So I think you can continue to write your code and copy the Bradley's code to check the Outlook version. Just like the following:

```
var version = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application().Version.Substring(0,2);
        int major = (int)Decimal.Parse(version);
        switch (major)
        {
            case 12:
                return "Outlook 2007";
            case 14:
                return "Outlook 2010";
            case 15:
                return "Outlook 2013";
            case 16:
                return "Outlook 2016";
        }
```